# Is there a way to customize comment() in mql4?

Tags: mql4

is there a way to customize the color/font/size of comment() function in mql4???.
because the text is too small. I want to be more creative in this part. Thank you in adavance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment is only text. You can use objects to set text and change most attributes.

Example:

```
string id="ObjectName";
ObjectCreate    (0, id, OBJ_LABEL, 0, 0, 0);
ObjectSet       (id, OBJPROP_CORNER, 0);
ObjectSet       (id, OBJPROP_XDISTANCE, 10);
ObjectSet       (id, OBJPROP_YDISTANCE, 10);
ObjectSetText   (id, "Text", 10, "Arial", clrRed);
```